# Errors in building u boot

Tags: build, compilation, arm, cross-compiling, u-boot

I am new to u boot. I downloaded the source for latest u boot source

```
   ftp://ftp.denx.de/pub/u-boot/
```

After downloading I am trying to build it following steps as given

```
   http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootConfiguration
```

But doing  'make all' give me errors

```
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/config.h
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk
 /bin/sh: 1: ppc_8xx-gcc: not found
 make[1]: *** [include/autoconf.mk] Error 1
 make: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed
 by `include/config/uboot.release'.  Stop.
```

I do not have any board. I am just trying to compile it as it is for any given configuration. How to do it as I am not getting any specific source to understand it.

Comment: Well I am not trying to be shakespeeerree here. If you have some proper answer please do comment otherwise do not bother.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you haven't performed a `make [board]_config`.  This is necessary to generate a target for `make`.

Another good example of this is at the [Toradex developer website](http://developer.toradex.com/software-resources/arm-family/linux/board-support-package/build-u-boot-and-linux-kernel-from-source-code).  You can see several different board configs are listed.  You must configure a board prior to executing `make`.